# Uninstall Anaconda Completely

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda

I uninstalled anaconda since I was having issues creating environments. I did this using add/remove programs (windows) but now there seems to be some files left. And it's not possible to install anaconda in the same location. Any ideas on how I can remove the remaining files so I can reinstall in the same location (i.e c:/users/imantha)

Comment: Uninstalling an Anaconda is a real pain. Haven't tried on windows. Good luck though :)

Comment: It is quite likely that removing the directory where you did install it in the first place, and possibly some `.conda` directory in your user dir (perhaps AppsData) will be enough. I do not think you need to touch the registry.