# Uninstalling Anaconda removed my command prompt

Tags: windows, shell, anaconda

I've installed Anaconda for data science onto my computer (http://anaconda.com/) for data science through Python.
as I've gone through the workflows for the course, i encountered issues setting up a virtual environment so I skipped this and used the default environment.

Because of the size of the package, I tried unistalling this using windows Add/Remove programs but now my command prompt is no longer working.
I tried recovering it using powershell but powershell opened with the prompt:

& : The term 'C:\Alan\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, \function, script
\file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the \path is correct
\and try again.
\At C:\Users\Alan Curley\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1:4 char:4

(& "C:\Alan\Python\Anaconda3\Scripts\conda.exe" "shell.powershell" "h ...
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (C:\Alan\Python...ripts\conda.exe:String) [], \CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException

indicating that the removal of anaconda and its environments failed and left some stuff behind.

I tried following the link at:
[Uninstall Anaconda Completely](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428378/uninstall-anaconda-completely)
to re-install anaconda but because my command prompt wont start it wont run anaconda or conda to install "clean anaconda".

Now I'm down any programs that rely on my command prompt to work and I've no idea where to start - any help?

Comment: Both cmd and the powershell console produce the same error? It sounds like the issue might be in your PATH? Try seeing if there's anything Conda-related you need to remove.

Answer (score 6):

I found the issue with my command prompt.
After some additional digging into the command prompt and issues with the command prompt, I came across the link:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-performance-winpc/command-prompt-in-windows-10-flashes-but-wont-stay/e539c3d2-8b1d-433f-82aa-db3944dae0de

using this, I tried calling the command prompt cmd.exe /d to exclude any autorun operations (Further research:
[https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html#:~:text=To%20specify%20an%20AutoRun%20value,it%20at%20the%20command%20prompt](https://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html#:%7E:text=To%20specify%20an%20AutoRun%20value,it%20at%20the%20command%20prompt).
)

and my command prompt worked ok again but not if I called up the /d.
I searched the autorun in the registry and there was a part entry:

"if exist  "
[image]

I removed the autorun entry from the registry registry completely and i was then able to re-install and de-install anaconda again.
Hopefully it's gone for good this time.

Comment: Happened to me, probably due to I have setted up Anaconda prompt to be the default console on Windows 10. The anaconda auto clean doesn't solves this, beware of that. This was very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error message in the Windows PowerShell. My Command Prompt worked fine tho. What worked for me is to follow the given path.
In your case that would be :
"\Users\Alan Curley\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1"
and comment the line that references conda.
I could even delete the entire file.